# Compiling two queries of similar data into one view with SQL

Tags: sql, join, merge, teradata

Apologies for the generic terms here and please let me know if there's not enough detail.

The Structure

Table1 contains information of when users log into a specific system
Table2 contains information of when users log into another system
Table3 contains user specific information

The request - Build 1 query that shows in one table an accurate timeline of the user logging into both systems.

The issues -

1. Users can start a task in one system and not complete it, leaving it in a pending state.  Because of this there is no end timestamp in that system.  I would like to find the next chronological timestamp and use that -1 second as the end ts for the 'pending' task.  (Users may never complete said task)
2. I've created the combined view using a union, however this seems inefficient and with it I'm not sure how to resolve issue 1. So I'm trying to find a way to build 1 non-union query that merges the values into their respective columns and from there apply any additional logic to determine the end_ts so there are no null values.

```sql
select 

a.uid as "user's ID",
a.first_name as "First Name",
a.last_name as "Last Name",


e.task_started_ts as "start_gmt_ts", //<-- I'd like to use the next val if previous end was null
e.task_ended_ts as "end_gmt_ts", //<-- This ts may be null
e.task_desc_cd as "task",

(extract(day from (e.task_ended_ts - e.task_started_ts DAY(4) TO SECOND)) * 86400) +
(extract(hour from (e.task_ended_ts - e.task_started_ts DAY(4) TO SECOND)) * 3600) +
(extract(minute from (e.task_ended_ts - e.task_started_ts DAY(4) TO SECOND)) * 60) +
extract(second from (e.task_ended_ts - e.task_started_ts DAY(4) TO SECOND))
as duration_secs,

e.task_created_ts as "created_at",
e.task_created_date as "reporting date"

from foo.Table1 e

JOIN baz.Table3 a ON a.users_db_id = e.users_db_id 
    and date BETWEEN a.role_start AND a.role_end

where 1=1

and e.users_db_id is in ('42')
and e.task_created_date > '2019-03-15'

UNION

SELECT

  e.uid as "user's ID",
  e.first_name as "First Name",
  e.last_name as "Last Name",
  c.task_started_ts as "start_gmt_ts", //<-- I'd like to use the next val if previous end was null
  c.task_ended_ts as "end_gmt_ts",
  case 
       when task_desc_code = '0' then 'task0'
       when task_desc_code = '1' then 'task1'
       when task_desc_code = '2' then 'task2'
       when task_desc_code = '3' then 'task3'
       when task_desc_code = '4' then 'task4'
       when task_desc_code = '5' then 'task5'       
       when task_desc_code = '6' then 'task6'
       when task_desc_code = '7' then 'task7'
       when task_desc_code = '8' then 'task8'
       when task_desc_code = '9' then 'task9'
       when task_desc_code = '10' then 'task10'
       else task_desc_code end as task,

  case when total_time_seconds = 0 then
    (extract(day from (c.task_ended_ts - c.task_started_ts DAY(4) TO SECOND)) * 86400) +
    (extract(hour from (c.task_ended_ts - c.task_started_ts DAY(4) TO SECOND)) * 3600) +
    (extract(minute from (c.task_ended_ts - c.task_started_ts DAY(4) TO SECOND)) * 60) +
    extract(second from (c.task_ended_ts - c.task_started_ts DAY(4) TO SECOND))
  else total_time_seconds end as duration_secs,

  c.task_created_ts as "created_at",
  c.task_created_date as "reporting date"

FROM bar.Table2 c
JOIN baz.Table3 e ON e.users_db_id = c.users_db_id 
  AND date BETWEEN e.role_start AND e.role_end
  WHERE c.task_created_date >= '2019-03-15' 
  AND e.uid in ('42')
```

As you can see from above each query creates the same columns with the same values.  I'd prefer to not use Union and find a way to pull the data from two tables and splice it together based on the chronological order of the start timestamps.  Then, when I run across a null end timestamp, I can  subtract 1 second from the next time start time stamp and use that as the end timestamp.

Not sure if this is possible or where to go from here.  Any help is appreciated

Comment: if you are sure you do not have any duplicates in your queries, use `union all` instead, it will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, `UNION ALL` the records from `Table1` and `Table2` and then do calculations and join them elsewhere, something like:

```
SELECT usrs.uid as "user's ID"
     , usrs.first_name as "First Name"
     , usrs.last_name as "Last Name"
     , both_systems.task_started_ts as "start_gmt_ts" //<-- I'd like to use the next val if previous end was null
     , both_systems.task_ended_ts as "end_gmt_ts" //<-- This ts may be null
     , both_systems.task_desc_cd as "task"

     , (extract(day from (both_systems.task_ended_ts - both_systems.task_started_ts DAY(4) TO SECOND)) * 86400) +
       (extract(hour from (both_systems.task_ended_ts - both_systems.task_started_ts DAY(4) TO SECOND)) * 3600) +
       (extract(minute from (both_systems.task_ended_ts - both_systems.task_started_ts DAY(4) TO SECOND)) * 60) +
       extract(second from (both_systems.task_ended_ts - both_systems.task_started_ts DAY(4) TO SECOND))
     as duration_secs

     , both_systems.task_created_ts as "created_at",
     , both_systems.task_created_date as "reporting date"
  FROM (-- Select as many columns as you need, just make sure columns are the same between both tables
       SELECT '1' AS system_in_use, c.task_started_ts, c.task_ended_ts, c.task_desc_code, c.users_db_id , c.total_time_seconds, c.task_created_ts, c.task_created_date, c.date
         FROM foo.Table1 c
        UNION ALL
       SELECT '2' AS system_in_use, c.task_started_ts, c.task_ended_ts, c.task_desc_code, c.users_db_id , c.total_time_seconds, c.task_created_ts, c.task_created_date, c.date
         FROM bar.Table2 c) both_systems
  JOIN baz.Table3 usrs
    ON usrs.users_db_id = c.both_systems
    -- not sure where date column is coming from, I presume task
    -- hint: never use non-qualified column names in multi-table queries
   AND both_systems.date BETWEEN usrs.role_start AND usrs.role_end
 WHERE both_systems.task_created_date >= '2019-03-15' 
   AND usrs.uid in ('42')
```

Now as to using next task's start date as the end date in case the end date of the current task is NULL, use [`LEAD`](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/756LNiPSFdY~4JcCCcR5Cw/GjCT6l7trjkIEjt~7Dhx4w). Something like:

```
COALESCE(both_systems.task_ended_ts, LEAD(both_systems.task_started_ts IGNORE NULLS, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY usrs.uid ORDER BY both_systems.task_started_ts)) AS task_ended_ts
```

So first, take `tasks_ended_ts` and only if it's `NULL`, find the following row using `LEAD`.

You'll probably need another subquery if you also want to calculate `duration_secs` using this formula.